# What kind of pump do I need to help a basement toilet flush?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, basement, toilet

I have a basement bathroom with a Pittsburgh toilet, raised about 10". It flushes but not well. I have seen pumps that run from $100 to $1000 and it appears many are for the install process. Can I buy a pump to help my existing toilet flush, what kind, and do I need a plumber or just the right tools? I'm fairly handy with basic home repairs, just not sure if this is outside the skillset of installing a faucet and such

Comment: Rather than spend hundreds on a pump, maybe replace the toilet.  The water in the tank and gravity should allow any toilet to flush well.  You may also have a drain issue and the drain line may not be vented well, if at all.  There are many questions to be answered before going the pump route.

Comment: After replacing an old basement toilet that flushed poorly with an inexpensive (~US$200) low-flush toilet, I was greatly surprised that it now works perfectly! Though I cannot give a specific product recommendation, you might check with hardware store and plumbers.